# Android JSON

Tags: android, java, json

Объект json имеет в себе то что нужно, а именно данные с сайта и отлично выводит их в Log.d().

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PID", pid));
// получаем JSON строк с URL
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_product_detials, "GET", params);
Log.d(TAG_DEBUG,json.getString("created_at"));
```

Но при попытке получить значение из строки json, она возвращает null, в чем может быть беда? получаю значение из json сразу после создания json.

```
Log.d(TAG_DEBUG,json.getString("created_at"));
тут выводит Null

Log.d(TAG_DEBUG,json.toString());
выводит весь объект и все отлично находит.
```

То что created_at есть, это 100%, проверял. и другие значения тоже...

Comment: Возможно проблема в массиве/объекте, который вы могли случайно пропустить. Пожалуйста, выложите образец JSON, который вы парсите.

Comment: {"product":[{"created_at":"2014-03-14 22:51:34","pid":"15","updated_at":null,"price":"522","description":"fffffffff","name":"product2"}],"success":1}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы пропустили JSONArray, как я и говорил.

```
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_product_detials, "GET", params);
JSONObject obj = json.getJSONArray("product").getJSONObject(0);
Log.d(TAG_DEBUG, obj.getString("created_at");
```

Вот вам на будущее небольшая шпаргалка:
[image: Различие между JSONArray и JSONObject]

Comment: Спасибо, я то массив пробовал, но не так)